# Boost regex to capture all repeated patterns

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have a simple text file with the following contents:

```
VALUE "foo"
ANOTHERVALUE "bar"
YETANOTHERVALUE "barbar"
```

The values in column 1 are known.

I want to capture everything in column 1 and in column 2.

My solution involves manually writing all the possible values of column 1 (which is known), into the regex string but obviously this is not ideal practice since I am basically repeating code and this does not allow the ordering to be flexible:

```
const char* re =
     "^[[:space:]]*"
     "(VALUE)[[:space:]]*\"(.*)\"[[:space:]]*"
     "(ANOTHERVALUE)[[:space:]]*\"(.*)\"[[:space:]]*"
     "(YETANOTHERVALUE)[[:space:]]*\"(.*)\"[[:space:]]*";
```

Comment: Regular expressions capture exactly as many substrings as there are left parentheses in the expression (roughly; there's a syntax for non-capturing group, so there could be fewer captures than parentheses - but there can't be more). `(something)+` will only capture the first occurrence of `something`, not all of them. The right way to solve this problem is to write a regex that matches a single pair, and apply it repeatedly, e.g. via `std::regex_iterator` (there's probably an equivalent in Boost, which I'm not really familiar with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm citing commenter Igor Tandetnik here, because he almost gave the complete answer in his comment:

> Regular expressions capture exactly as many substrings as there are
> left parentheses in the expression [...]
>
> The right way to solve this problem is to write a regex that matches a
> single pair, [...]

```
\s*([a-zA-Z]+)\s*"(.*?)"
```

Notes:

- `\s` is equivalent to `[[:space:]]`
- `.*?` is used to stop searching after the 2nd `"` instead of the last `"` in the string

> and apply it repeatedly, e.g. via std::regex_iterator

The boost equivalent is [boost::regex_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_iterator.html).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

const boost::regex expr{ R"__(\s*([a-zA-Z]+)\s*"(.*?)")__" };

const std::string s =
R"(VALUE "foo" 
ANOTHERVALUE "bar" 
YETANOTHERVALUE "barbar"
)";
    
int main() {
    boost::sregex_iterator it{ begin(s), end(s), expr }, itEnd;
    
    std::for_each( it, itEnd, []( const boost::smatch& m ){
        std::cout << m[1] << '\n' << m[2] << std::endl;
    });
}
```

[Live demo.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/T5VK7HDgNBRYBKwW)

Notes:

- I'm using raw [string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) to make the code cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a little Spirit Parser here:

### Reading Into A Map

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3864dd70b05eab74)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp> // reading maps
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_istream_iterator.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>

auto read_config_map(std::istream& stream) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> settings;

    boost::spirit::istream_iterator f(stream >> std::noskipws), l;
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

    auto key_ = lexeme [ +upper ];
    auto value_ = lexeme [ '"' >> *~char_('"') >> '"' ];

    if (!phrase_parse(f, l, -(key_ >> value_) % eol >> eoi, blank, settings))
        throw std::invalid_argument("cannot parse config map");

    return settings;
}

auto read_config_map(std::string const& fname) {
    std::ifstream stream(fname);
    return read_config_map(stream);
}

int main() {
    for (auto&& entry : read_config_map(std::cin))
        std::cout << "Key:'" << entry.first << "' Value:'" << entry.second << "'\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
Key:'ANOTHERVALUE' Value:'bar'
Key:'VALUE' Value:'foo'
Key:'YETANOTHERVALUE' Value:'barbar'
```